# differential series solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

So I have been trying to figure out where I am going wrong with this question. I think it is to do with the index shifting, my book has given a model solution which has confused me more. I will try and show and explain where my problem is.

Q. Substitute the power series for cos x into the differntial equation

$$y''=-y$$

so my starting point is here:

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n*\frac{x^{2n}}{2n!}$

by taking the differntial I get:

$\frac{d}{dx}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n*\frac{x^{2n}}{2n!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$

I have set the lower limit as n=1 beacuse the series shifts one place to the right.

Now this is the part where I seem to get lost. Taking the second differential I get:

$\frac{d}{dx}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}=\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n-2}}{(2n-2)!}$ The reason being that when it has been differentiate twice it has shifted another place. But obviously this can't be correct as I know that this series does not give $-\sin x$.

Now my book solution is for the second differential is:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n-2}}{(2n-2)!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

which does equal $-\sin x$, but I just can't seem to see how this has been done. Could someone please expand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2n - 2 } /(2n-2)!
$$
 lets manipulate it a little.

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2n - 2 } /(2n-2)! = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2(n - 1) } /(2(n-1))! \\ /j = n-1/ \\ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{j+1} x^{2j} /(2j)!
$$

So, in your solution given in the book, you have a different $n$ in the final answer.

Comment: AH! okay I cant believe I miss that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, I've been there too, and I will be there again. @JasonTaylor